# a different design pattern for this solution

Tags: java, design-patterns

**I am having an interface that holds three different methods. And there are two class Car and Plane which will implement the Vehicle interface to get access to those methods. There are two questions that I have in my mind.**

***1. What type of design pattern satisfies the following implementation?***

***2. Is there any other design pattern to satisfy similar kinds of functionalities?***

Though **I have tried some blogs and questions I have found one answer regarding the second question which is using Anonymous Class** but which leads to more garbage code. So is there any solution or answer to my questions?

```
public interface Vehicle {
    int set_num_of_wheels();
    int set_num_of_passengers();
    boolean has_gas();
}
```

```
public class Car implements Vehicle{

    @Override
    public int set_num_of_wheels() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int set_num_of_passengers() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean has_gas() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

```
public class Plane implements Vehicle{

    @Override
    public int set_num_of_wheels() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int set_num_of_passengers() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean has_gas() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think implementing an interface is a pattern. It's a fundamental OO construct:  polymorphism.

Comment: BTW, you should really learn and stick to the Java naming conventions. And not call `set` a method that actually *gets*.

Comment: [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example)?

Comment: @ElliotFrisch It wouldn't be a visitor, since there is no dispatching taking place. I'd agree that it's nothing more than polymorphism.

Comment: @JBNizet those methods I have added in my code, it was just sampled that's why there is no proper set and get.

Comment: [Mark Grand documented the interface pattern](https://books.google.ca/books?id=810chlr-IQgC&lpg=PA87&ots=n4e02jCzOU&dq=mark%20grand%20interface%20pattern&pg=PA63#v=onepage&q=Interface%20pattern&f=false) on page 61.

Comment: You can also use the delegate pattern (composition rather than inheritance) because it is more flexible.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator , your answer seems much obvious and I have tried the delegate design pattern. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism is just a fancy way to put different function pointers (chosen inconditionally by the concrete class) under a given function name.

So instead if you had a single class with a hashmap of methodenum-to-somefunctioninterface (method enum would just list the finite set of methods to hookup), then you could call the polymorphic functions by looking them up by the enum in the map, then casting to somefunctioninterface and calling it.

It entirely defeats the purpose of this OOP language, but that would be a distinct implementation.

It would fall into behavioral patterns for sure, but I guess it would be close to a Strategy or Plugin, given it's about delegating to classes incarnating the function.

BTW, that's pretty much what DynamicProxy is trying to do; proxy the interface without any impl class and delegate to a handler which figures a way to respon to the requested method.